# Question regarding the proof of a topological claim

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The lecturer in the Topology course I'm taking defined the following:
Given a topological space $X$
  we say that:

1. $X$ is weakly locally compact if for all $x\in X$
   there exists a compact nbhd.
2. $X$ is strongly locally compact if every nbhd of $x$
   contains a compact nbhd of $x$
   .

We then made the following claim: A weakly locally compact (wlc) Hausdorff space is strongly locally compact.

Briefly the proof went as follows:

1. Given $U$ a nbhd of $x\in X$  since $X$ is wlc there is a compact nbhd of $x$
   , $C\subseteq X$.
2. Since $U,C$
   are both nbhds of $x$ then $U\cap C$
   is also a nbhd of $x$
   and thus there is an open set $V\subseteq X$
   such that $x\in V\subseteq U\cap C$
   .
3. Since $C$
   is a compact Hausdorff space (Hausdorff being hereditary) we know $C$
   is regular.
4. Since regularity is hereditary and $V\subseteq C$
   we know $V$
   is also regular and thus there is an open set $W\subseteq V$
   such that $x\in W\subseteq\overline{W}\subseteq V\subseteq C$ .
5. Since $C$
   is compact and $\overline{W}$
   is closed in $C$
   we know that $\overline{W}$
   is also compact.
6. Finally $x\in W\subseteq\overline{W}\subseteq V\subseteq U$
   and thus $\overline{W}$
   is a compact nbhd of $x$
   contained in $U$ .

The lecturer then noted that it's important to notice the proof hangs on the fact that the closure of $W$ in $V$ and $C$ is the same. That is since we can only deduce compactness of $\overline{W}$ since it is closed in $C$. However, we used the regularity of $V$ in order to find $W$ and thus the closure of $W$ is relative to the topology in $V$ and not in $C$. He also noted that in fact from the way we carried out the construction the closure of $W$ is the same in all the groups in which it is contained, that is $\overline{W}_{X}=\overline{W}_{C}=\overline{W}_{U}=\overline{W}_{V}$
  (the substring marking closure relative to which space).

My question is why is it in fact true that $\overline{W}_{X}=\overline{W}_{C}=\overline{W}_{U}=\overline{W}_{V}$ ?

Comment: Note that $C$ is regular, so there is an open $W$ such that $\overline W$ is a subset of $V$, and the closure is taken with respect to $C$.

Comment: That's true I can take the closure relative to $C$ right away and the proof would be correct without any messing around. That still doesn't explain the claim that $\overline{W}_{X}=\overline{W}_{C}=\overline{W}_{U}=\overline{W}_{V}$ though.

Comment: @StefanH. I tried taking up your "challenge" to find a similar formula for the interior and ran into a bit of trouble. I couldn't "ping" you in a comment there so I thought I'd ping you here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a useful formula: If $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $W$ is another subset, then $\text{cl}_A(W\cap A)=\text{cl}_X(W\cap A)\cap A$. So let $A$ be the $V$ in your example.
If we take the closure of $W$ with respect to $C$, then $\text{cl}_C(W)=\text{cl}_X(W)$ since $C$ is closed in $X$.
On the other hand $\text{cl}_V(W)=\text{cl}_X(W)\cap V$ which is just $\text{cl}_X(W)$ since $W$ was chosen to have its closure contained in $V$.
Finally, $\text{cl}_U(W)=\text{cl}_X(W)\cap U=\text{cl}_X(W)$ since $\text{cl}(W)\subset U$.

I should also mention that the above formula simplifies one more time if $A$ is open. In this case we have $\text{cl}_A(W\cap A)=\text{cl}_X(W\cap A)\cap A=\text{cl}_X(W)\cap A$. Using this the last two equalities follow automatically since $U$ and $V$ were open.

Comment: A useful formula indeed :) 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! If you want, you can try to find a similar formula for the interior :-)

Comment: I decided to take your suggestion, initially I thought it just might be analogues so that $\mbox{Int}_{A}\left(W\cap A\right)=\mbox{Int}_{X}\left(W\cap A\right)\cap A$ but the same reasoning that works for proving the closure identity doesn't really work here. 
I then tried going from the definition: $\mbox{Int}_{A}\left(W\cap A\right)=\bigcup\left\{ U\in\mathcal{T}_{A}\,|\, U\subseteq W\cap A\right\} =\bigcup\left\{ U\in\mathcal{T}_{X}\,|\, U\cap A\subseteq W\cap A\right\}$ but I don't really see where I can take this to. Is there actually such a handy formula for the interior?

Comment: @Serpahimz: There is. To derive it from the previous formula, express $\text{int}_A(W\cap A)$ as $A-\text{cl}_A(A-W)$. According to the formula for the relative closure, this is equal to $A-(\text{cl}_X(A-W)\cap A)=A-\text{cl}_X(A-W)=A\cap\text{int}_X(X-(A-W))=A\cap\text{int}_X(W\cup(X-A))$, so this formula is a bit less intuitive. Again, if $A$ is open, one can prove that $\text{int}_A(W\cap A)=\text{int}_X(X\cap A)\cap A$.

Comment: Hey Stefan, in both cases I'm having trouble showing the simplification of the formula in case $A$ is open. Could you elaborate on that?
Actually only in the first formula. the second simplification is simple.

Comment: @Serpahimz: Of course. Let $x\in\text{cl}_X(W)\cap A$. To show that it is in the relative closure, we need to show that for any open $U\ni x$ the relative neighborhood $U\cap A$ intersects $W\cap A$. But $A$ is open and $x\in A$, so $U\cap A$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, which intersects $W$, thus also $W\cap A$. Hence $x\in\text{cl}_A(W\cap A)$.

Comment: On second thought the simplification in the interior seems a bit odd since $\mbox{Int}_{X}\left(X\cap A\right)\cap A=\mbox{Int}_{X}\left(A\right)\cap A=\mbox{Int}_{X}\left(A\right)$ so you end up with $\mbox{Int}_{A}\left(W\cap A\right)=\mbox{Int}_{X}\left(A\right)$

Comment: @Serpahimz: There's obviously a typo, but giving it a second thought, one can refine it a bit and obtains $\text{int}_A(W\cap A)=\text{int}_X(W\cap A)=\text{int}_X(W)\cap A$.

Comment: Ye I figured there was a typo :)
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, you've been very kind.